# Sharing data between list view and detail view with angular

Tags: angularjs, listview, detailview, dataservice

I would like create a simple e-commerce in angular, but i have a big problem.
How to create a list view and when i click on a item go to detail view with $params and data Service ?

**Service**

```
app.service("productService", function (filterFilter, $http, $routeParams) {

var items = [];

var promise = $http.get('process/product-view.php').then(function (res){

    return items = res.data;

});

this.getProducts = function (){

    return promise;

};


this.getProductAt = function(_name) {


    return promise.then(function (res){

        console.log(JSON.stringify(items));

        return filterFilter(items, {

            link_page: _name

        })[0];
    });
};
});
```

**Controllers**

*shop*

```
app.controller('shop', ['$scope', '$http', 'productService', function ($scope, $http, productService){

productService.getProducts().then(function (res){
    $scope.products = res;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
}]);
```

*single-item*

```
app.controller('single-item', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'productService', function ($scope, $routeParams, productService){
    $scope.product = productService.getProductAt($routeParams.item);

}]);
```

Thanks !

Comment: check over your code formatting, it looks like some of the code bits have fallen outside of the blocks and it makes it harder to understand

Comment: Have you checked out the official AngularJS [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)? There you will build something very similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is my first question on stackoverflow, my code is difficult to listen because don't understand directly the markup system. (and sorry for my bad english ^^). @muenchdo : thanks, i listen tutorial but i would like pass multiple variable on detail view not just name but the name, price and other informations. How to do ?